# Converting empty string to a None in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a requirement to concatenate two potentially empty address lines into one (with a space in between the two lines), but I need it to return a `None` if both address lines are `None` (this field is going into an `Option[String]` variable).  The following command gets me what I want in terms of the concatenation:

```
Seq(myobj.address1, myobj.address2).flatten.mkString(" ")
```

But that gives me an empty string instead of a `None` in case address1 and address2 are both `None`.

Comment: They are both Option[String] and the resultant value will also go into an Option[String].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, In Scala there is `Option[ T ]` type which is intended to eliminate various run-time problems due to nulls.

So... Here is how you use Options, So basically a `Option[ T ]` can have one of the two types of values - `Some[ T ]` or `None`

```
// A nice string
var niceStr = "I am a nice String"

// A nice String option
var noceStrOption: Option[ String ] = Some( niceStr )

// A None option
var noneStrOption: Option[ String ] = None
```

Now coming to your part of problem:

```
// lets say both of your myobj.address1 and myobj.address2 were normal Strings... then you would not have needed to flatten them... this would have worked..
var yourString = Seq(myobj.address1, myobj.address2).mkString(" ")

// But since both of them were Option[ String ] you had to flatten the Sequence[ Option[ String ] ] to become a Sequence[ String ]
var yourString = Seq(myobj.address1, myobj.address2).flatten.mkString(" ")

//So... what really happens when you flatten a Sequence[ Option[ String ] ] ?

// Lets say we have Sequence[ Option [ String ] ], like this
var seqOfStringOptions = Seq( Some( "dsf" ), None, Some( "sdf" ) )

print( seqOfStringOptions )
// List( Some(dsf), None, Some(sdf))

//Now... lets flatten it out...
var flatSeqOfStrings = seqOfStringOptions.flatten

print( flatSeqOfStrings )
// List( dsf, sdf )

// So... basically all those Option[ String ] which were None are ignored and only Some[ String ] are converted to Strings.

// So... that means if both address1 and address2 were None... your flattened list would be empty.

// Now what happens when we create a String out of an empty list of Strings...

var emptyStringList: List[ String ] = List()
var stringFromEmptyList = emptyStringList.mkString( " " )
print( stringFromEmptyList ) 
// ""
// So... you get an empty String

// Which means we are sure that yourString will always be a String... though it can be empty (ie - "").

// Now that we are sure that yourString will alwyas be a String, we can use pattern matching to get out Option[ String ] .

// Getting an appropriate Option for yourString
var yourRequiredOption: Option[ String ] = yourString match {
    // In case yourString is "" give None.
    case "" => None
    // If case your string is not "" give Some[ yourString ] 
    case someStringVal => Some( someStringVal )
}
```

Comment: The second-to-last line in your solution should have parentheses instead of square brackets.

Comment: why are you using `var`s instead of `val`s?

Comment: @dk14 for no reason at all... :p

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh I need to rephrase it: "OMG! why are you using `var` instead of `val`??!!!oneone 0_o". All you can respond to that is ["For Great Justice!"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=for+great+justice) :)

Comment: @dk14 For justice indeed... all those poor "vars"... hated by all scala programmers...

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Yeah! finally poor `print`s took revenge on `println`s! [All your base belong to us!](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=all+your+base+are+belong+to+us)

Answer (score 15):

This converts a single string to `Option`, converting it to `None` if it's either `null` or an empty-trimmed string:

*(kudos to @Miroslav Machura for this simpler version)*

```scala
Option(x).filter(_.trim.nonEmpty)
```

Alternative version, using `collect`:

```scala
Option(x).collect { case x if x.trim.nonEmpty => x }
```

Comment: This is definitely most idiomatic approach. One tiny simplification could be: `Option(x).filter(_.trim.nonEmpty)`

Answer (score 6):

Assuming:

```
val list1 = List(Some("aaaa"), Some("bbbb"))
val list2 = List(None, None)
```

Using plain Scala:

```
scala> Option(list1).map(_.flatten).filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.mkString(" "))
res38: Option[String] = Some(aaaa bbbb)

scala> Option(list2).map(_.flatten).filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.mkString(" "))
res39: Option[String] = None
```

Or using scalaz:

```
import scalaz._; import Scalaz._
scala> list1.flatten.toNel.map(_.toList.mkString(" "))
res35: Option[String] = Some(aaaa bbbb)

scala> list2.flatten.toNel.map(_.toList.mkString(" "))
res36: Option[String] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also use the `reduce` method here:

```
val mySequenceOfOptions = Seq(myAddress1, myAddress2, ...)

mySequenceOfOptions.reduce[Option[String]] {
    case(Some(soFar), Some(next)) => Some(soFar + " " + next)
    case(None, next) => next
    case(soFar, None) => soFar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that should solve the original problem.

```
def mergeAddresses(addr1: Option[String],
                   addr2: Option[String]): Option[String] = {
  val str = s"${addr1.getOrElse("")} ${addr2.getOrElse("")}"
  if (str.trim.isEmpty) None else Some(str)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the [answer from @dk14](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57414484/918858) is actually incorrect/incomplete because if `list2` has a `Some("")` it will not yield a `None` because the `filter()` evaluates to an empty list instead of a `None` ( [ScalaFiddle link](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/ebNVOZ4/0))

```scala
val list2 = List(None, None, Some(""))

// this yields Some()
println(Option(list2).map(_.flatten).filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.mkString(" ")))
```

but it's close.  you just need to ensure that empty string is converted to a `None` so [we combine it with @juanmirocks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57414484/918858) ([ScalaFiddle link](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/CLxFqQj/0)):

```scala
val list1 = List(Some("aaaa"), Some("bbbb"))
val list2 = List(None, None, Some(""))

// yields Some(aaaa bbbbb)
println(Option(list1.map(_.collect { case x if x.trim.nonEmpty => x }))
  .map(_.flatten).filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.mkString(" ")))
 
// yields None 
println(Option(list2.map(_.collect { case x if x.trim.nonEmpty => x }))
  .map(_.flatten).filter(_.nonEmpty).map(_.mkString(" ")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching a kind of helper function like below in the standard library but did not find yet, so I defined in the meantime:

```
 def string_to_Option(x: String): Option[String] = {
    
    if (x.nonEmpty)
      Some(x)
    else 
      None    
  }
```

with the help of the above you can then:

```
import scala.util.chaining.scalaUtilChainingOps

object TEST123 {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val address1 = ""
    val address2 = ""

    val result =
      Seq(
        address1 pipe string_to_Option,
        address2 pipe string_to_Option
      ).flatten.mkString(" ") pipe string_to_Option

    println(s"The result is «${result}»") 
    // prints out: The result is «None»
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Scala 2.13:

```
Option.unless(address.isEmpty)(address)
```

For example:

```
val address = "foo" 
Option.unless(address.isEmpty)(address) // Some("foo")
```

```
val address = "" 
Option.unless(address.isEmpty)(address) // None
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution that looks analogous to existing methods like `toIntOption` etc:

```
implicit class EmptyToNone(s: String):
  def toOption: Option[String] = if s.isEmpty then None else Some(s)
```

Examples:

```
scala> "".toOption
val res0: Option[String] = None

scala> "foo".toOption
val res1: Option[String] = Some(foo)

scala> "foo".toIntOption
val res2: Option[Int] = None

scala> "42".toIntOption
val res3: Option[Int] = Some(42)
```

(tested with Scala 3.2.2)